# Arguments of command line and into struct

Tags: c, struct, command-line-arguments

I am writing a program in C which has several arguments that I can type in command line when I am running it. For example:

```
./proj select row 3 <table.txt
```

to print the row num 3.

In my program I have lots of `if`/`else`. For example if argv[1] is select and argv[2] is row then do this, and so on. I showed it to my teacher and was told not to do this with if-else but with structure. And the problem is that I have no idea how. Could you give me some simple advice on how to start?

Comment: Hello, I am writing a program in c which has several arguments that I can type in command line when I am running it. For example ./proj select row 3 <table.txt. (print the row num 3).In my program I have lots of if - else....for example if argv[1] is select and argv[2] is row then do this:... etc...I showed it to my teacher and was told not to do this with if-else but with structure...and the problem is that I have no idea how. Could you give me some simple advices how to start? Thanks for answers

Comment: Without details of what you are trying to do, or the structure you want/need to use, assistance will be difficult at best.

Comment: You should show us the relevant part(s) of your program.

Comment: The program works with a table, with its rows and columns. argv[1] is the operations which I want to do, argv[2] tells if I work with a row/a col/rows/cols and other arguments are numbers of these rows, cols....and in main(int argc, char **argv) I should use struct or enum or something like that to recognize which arguments the program got to work with...my code is finished and works fine, but I must replace my "if-else" recognizing of arguments with struct or enum

Answer (score 0):

Process your command line options using `getopt`.  Here is an example:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html

In your case I think something like:

```
./proj -r 3 <table.txt
```

would be good.  So in your getopt while loop you'd check for the 'r' argument and store its value.  Then use that value in your code.  Something like:

```
int row_num = -1;
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "r:")) != -1)
    switch (c)
      {
      case 'r':
        row_num = optarg;
        break;
      case '?':
        if (optopt == 'r')
          fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
        else if (isprint (optopt))
          fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
        else
          fprintf (stderr,
                   "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n",
                   optopt);
        return 1;
      default:
        abort ();
      }
  printf ("row_num = %d\n", row_num);

  /* Now use your row_num variable here. */

  return 0;
}
```

Note that you could also have the name of the input file as an argument as well, then you wouldn't have to pipe it in like you are now.  Something like:

```
./proj -r 3 -f table.txt
```

You'll find more examples of getopt around the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points.

Firstly I'd do the parsing of the command line with `getopt_long()`.

```
#include <getopt.h>

int opt = 0;
int opt_index = 0;
static const char sopts[] = "s:";                    /* Short options */
static const struct option lopts[] = {               /* Long options  */
            {"select",   required_argument, NULL, 's'},
            {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
    };

while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, sopts, lopts, &opt_index)) != -1) {
    /* use a switch/case statement to parse the arguments */
}
```

Secondly in the case of using a structure. Something along the lines of this comes to mind:

```
struct opts {
    int num;
    char *select;
}
```

So as to place the row number into `num` and the select variable (`row` in your case) into the `select` array.

Of course you need to fill in the remainder of the code. But this is a start and a point in that direction.